# How to do pagination for react bootstrap pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am working on the development of a web-based app using React.js. I have used axios to get the data from the sqlite database and an I'm successful in displaying the data in the react bootstrap table. However, the data list is quite long and I have to use pagination to look into the data.

Here is my code for the react table-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SignInForm from "./SignInForm";
import SignUpForm from "./SignUpForm";
import { getElementError } from "@testing-library/react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as ReactBootStrap from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from 'axios';
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator.min.css';  

class HomePage extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();

   this.state = {
    storage:[
      {
        name:"",
        weight:"",
        height:"",
      }
    ],
    options:"",
    data:"",
    //storage: [],
   };
 
 
 } 

 componentDidMount () {
   axios
   .get('http://localhost:9000/users/patientDetails')
   .then((res) => { const storage = res.data;
            this.setState({storage})
   })
   
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err);
   });
    
  
 }



 render() {
 
   const {storage} = this.state;
   
   
    const options = {  

                             page: 2,   
     
                             sizePerPageList: [ {  
     
                               text: '5', value: 5  
     
                             }, {  
     
     
                               text: '10', value: 10  
     
                             }, {  
     
                               text: 'All', value: this.state.storage.length  
     
                             } ],   
     
                             sizePerPage: 5,   
     
                             pageStartIndex: 0,   
     
                             paginationSize: 3,    
     
                             prePage: 'Prev',   
     
                             nextPage: 'Next',   
     
                             firstPage: 'First',   
     
                             lastPage: 'Last',   
                             paginationPosition: 'top'    
     
                           };  
return (
<div>
<ReactBootStrap.Table striped bordered hover variant=""  pagination={ paginationFactory(options) }>
               <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Weight</th>
             <th>Height</th>
             {/*<th>Status</th>*/}
           </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>
              
                { this.state.storage.map(person => 
                
                  <tr>
                  <td>{person.name}</td> 
                  <td>{person.weight}</td>
                  <td>{person.height}</td>
                  </tr>
                 
                
       )}
        
            
           </tbody>
                
         </ ReactBootStrap.Table>
   </div>
);
 }
}
```

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YDFT.png)

Comment: Basically chunk up your `storage` data and store the chunk "offset", i.e. what "page" you're rendering. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I've tried that.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried?

Comment: I have updated the code part and also added an image of the table output which I currently get. Hope this helps!